# Can all odd composites be expressed like this

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not a mathematician but I'm very interested in number theory. I was looking at set builder notation and it seemed to me that all odd composites might be expressed like this:

$$\{3k+kj ｜ k ≥ 3,  k \text{ is odd,}  j \text{ is even}\}$$

Is this fair to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming you allow $j=0$.  $$3k+kj=k(3+j)$$  Since an odd composite number has two odd factors that are each 3 or greater, you can express one of them as $k$ (which is odd) and take $j$ to be three less than the other (which would make $j$ even.

Comment: And if $j=0$ is disallowed, then we miss $9$ but do get all other odd composite numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure I understood what I was doing. By the way, do you know why my comment was downvoted? I don't mean to sound vain or anything like that but I'm interested in why my question is bad. Is the question too trivial or something for this website? In case I ask any questions in the future it would be nice to know what questions to ask and how.

Comment: Also, I made sure that j = 0 is allowed but I forgot to mention that j and k must be natural numbers.

Comment: @THETROLLEYTROLL I couldn't say.  Everybody's got their own vision of which posts to encourage or discourage.  Your result is certainly not groundbreaking, but I think that it's fair for you to ask why it should be true.

Comment: @THETROLLEYTROLL: It's not my downvote, but I suspect that the elementary character of the question _in combination with_ your username (and profile text!) has led someone to conclude you didn't mean the question seriously.

Comment: I hadn't thought of my name, haha. c'est la vie I suppose, anyway thank you both.

Comment: General help regarding posting questions and answers is given at https://math.stackexchange.com/help Also, comments regarding formatting are available at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Welcome to MSE !

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll make sure to read up on those pages. You guys have a wonderful community here, and since I would like to join it, I'm incredibly thankful for having received your advice.